# Possible to get crash when reloadItemsAtIndexPaths called with same indexes?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

Get a crash at this line when `newIndexPath` and `indexPath` are both the same `[0, 0]`. Is it possible it can cause crash?

```
case .Move:
      self.collectionView!.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!, indexPath!])
```

**Error message is**:

> -[UICollectionViewUpdateItem _isCell]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1289f4b90

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear: You have an instance of UICollectionViewUpdateItem that doesn't understand the message _isCell. Set a breakpoint on Objective-C exceptions to find out where this happens. Doesn't look like there is a problem with reloadItemsAtIndexPaths itself.

Comment: I set up `Objective-C exceptions`. It happens exact on this line.